# References on the topic of DEM and XDEM

Tags: finite-element, reference-request, simulation

DEM: discrete element method.
XDEM: extended discrete element method.

For my current project of furnace simulation with granular materials, I am interested in the methods mentioned above. I have not studied these method in the past and now I am looking for general introductory materials. Either monograph or scientific papers would be fine.

Comment: Can you list the materials your favourite search engines helped you find so that we don't waste your time with duplicate references.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I have access to most common search engines e.g. sciencedirect, csirus, webofknowledge, etc. I prefer to read an introductory book rather than scientific papers. Considering DEM has been a subject developed in the last half decade, there should be some good books accessible, or it is not true.

Comment: The question was: What have you already searched for and what have you read?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth As I said, the materials I found are journals, however I am looking for a reference book which contains more thorough treatment.

Comment: I dont know that DEM is a sufficiently general topic that you will find an introductory textbook on just that.  Broaden your search to mechanics of granular materials.